# webpack - how to load a chunked polyfill file as necessary

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, polyfills

So the recommended way to prevent loading polyfills if it's unnecessary is to put some logic in the `<head>` (original: https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/)

```
<script>
    var modernBrowser = (
        'fetch' in window &&
        'assign' in Object
    );

    if ( !modernBrowser ) {
        var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');

        scriptElement.async = false;
        scriptElement.src = './polyfills.bundle.js';
        document.head.appendChild(scriptElement);
    }
</script>
```

However, as my files are chunked, it will not be consistent e.g. `polyfills.b0d50a4c4d9ca24a9f43.js`.

So what's the best way to implement this logic (in webpack or just in the `index.html`)

**Note**

I work with Vue, so maybe I could just import it in the `App` component?

E.g.

```
var modernBrowser = (
    'fetch' in window &&
    'assign' in Object
);

if ( !modernBrowser ) {
    require("polyfill")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't `require` the polyfill like you did, cause the code of the polyfill will be always inside your bundle.

You need to make a chunk out of it, using `require.ensure` or `import()` syntax.

There is an [article](https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/) about it in webpack docs.

The idea is to create a file with you check, and then lazy load the polyfill.

//app entry point
   import myFramework from 'myFramework';

var modernBrowser = (
        'fetch' in window &&
        'assign' in Object
    );

```
function bootstrapTheApp() {
   myFramework.bootstrap();
}

if ( !modernBrowser ) {
    import("polyfill").then(() => {
       //polyfill loaded
       bootstrapTheApp();
    })
} else {
   bootstrapTheApp();
}
```

Comment: well, I can't really have it async, since polyfill needs to run first in order to be able to handle non-existent functions and such

Comment: So make the async request on your app entry point, wait for the polyfill to load and only then bootstrap the app.

Comment: I'll have to investigate that, since I'm not too great at webpack

Comment: check the snippet

Comment: Not sure how to implement that in terms of using Vue SFC.

Answer (score 1):

A great service is polyfill.io https://polyfill.io/v2/docs/ which, according to the calling browser, generates the right polyfill, very configurable